# Codigo de c# para poder establecer fecha de Quincenas

Tags: c#

Estoy elaborando un sistema de prestamos para mi empresa y estoy trancado en generar las fechas de mis cuotas. Por ejemplo.

Esto es en C#

Cuando genere por Quincena las cuotas del préstamo quiero que solo me enumere del mes los días 15 y 30, y ver como tomar en cuenta de que febrero es de 28 y coloque ese en vez del día 30. Les agradecería grandemente. Tengo varias semanas buscando la respuesta a esto pero no la encuentro por ninguna parte esta documentación.

Por ejemplo:

Prestamo a 2 mes con 4 cuotas:

Cuota 1:   15/04/2023

Cuota 2:   30/04/2023

Cuota 3:   15/05/2023

Cuota 4:   30/05/2023

Este es el código que he estado utilizando hasta ahora

```
DateTime fechaInicio;
TipoPago oTipoPago = listaPago.Where(tp =>
tp.IdTipoPago== Convert.ToInt32(((OpcionCombo)cbotipopago.SelectedItem).Valor.ToString())).FirstOrDefault();
fechaInicio = Convert.ToDateTime(txtfechainicio.Text);
DateTime fechacuotapago = fechaInicio;

fechacuotapago = fechacuotapago.AddDays(-1);
ListaCuota = new List<Cuota>();

if (oTipoPago.AplicaDias == 1)
{
    fechacuotapago = fechacuotapago.AddDays(1);
    
    for (int i = 1; i <= nrocuotas; i++)
    {
        fechacuotapago = fechacuotapago.AddDays(oTipoPago.Valor);

        ListaCuota.Add(new Cuota()
        {
            NumeroCuota = i,
            FechaPagoCuota = fechacuotapago.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", new CultureInfo("en-US")),
            MontoCuota = i == 1 ? (cociente + residuo) : cociente,
            EstadoCuota = "PENDIENTE",
            ProximoPago = i == 1 ? 1 : 0
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Y el código que haz llevado hasta ahora?

Comment: Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: En que rango te interesan las quincenas, de que fecha a que fecha?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes ver si los días que le restan al mes son menos que 15, en ese caso sumarías la cantidad de días que falten y no 15.

```
DateTime AgregarMedioMes(DateTime date){
    int diasEnMes = DateTime.DaysInMonth(date.Year, date.Month);
    int diasRestantes = diasEnMes - date.Day;
    int diasAAgregar = Math.Min(diasRestantes, 15);
    return date.AddDays(diasAAgregar);
}
```

Más información de [`DaysInMonth`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.datetime.daysinmonth?view=net-7.0#system-datetime-daysinmonth(system-int32-system-int32)).

Comment: Que parte de mi código tendría que sustituir en este caso?

Comment: @joelRomero donde sea que estés sumando 15 días, reemplazalo por una llamada a la función que sugiero.